# x2go do not connect to active desktop session

Tags: lubuntu, lxde, x2go, lxsession

I have an Ubuntu Server 16.04 installation that I later added Lubuntu desktop to.
I then installed the x2go server (and the client on my Lubuntu 18.04 laptop).

For some years everything worked like a charm, connecting to the users active display session (to get that to work I had to change the session type to: "customized desktop" with the additional command:

```
lxsession -s Lubuntu -e LXDE
```

Sometime around February 2019, several new updates were installed and the server was restarted. After this, the client always gets a new fresh desktop session, rather than connecting to the users already running session. At the site you can still see the open windows for the local user.

I have tried use session type "connect to local desktop" but that only results in a "black screen".

How to fix this?

**Additional info:**

Connecting to server with `ssh` when no x2go client connected, and running the  command `x2golistdesktops` returns:

```
username@:0
```

After connecting with the client (and getting a new session), running the same command results in:

```
username@:0
username@:50
```

This just confirms that the server spawns the desktop session, however the client states that it connects to `:0`.

---

```
Loop: WARNING! Overriding auxiliary X11 port with new value '1'.
Warning: Overriding auxiliary X11 port with new value '1'.
Info: Using abstract X11 socket in kernel namespace for accessing DISPLAY=:0.
```

---

Any ideas ?

Comment: did you find a solution?  I'm experiencing the same or very similar problem.